# How to inspect incoming XML from Web Reference?

Tags: c#, soap, reference, paypal

We are calling the *Paypal Soap API* and running into

```
{"The specified type was not recognized: name='OptionDetailsType', namespace='urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents', at <OptionDetails xmlns='urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI'>."}
```

Which is true, because `OptionDetailsType` is not in `urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents` but in `urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI`.  I suspect that this is specified in the incoming *XML* from **Paypal**, but I'm not sure how to inspect the incoming **XML**.  The code dies at the Invoke in Reference.cs

```
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderAttribute("RequesterCredentials", Direction=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderDirection.InOut)]
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
[return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("BMGetButtonDetailsResponse", Namespace="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI")]
public BMGetButtonDetailsResponseType BMGetButtonDetails([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI")] BMGetButtonDetailsReq BMGetButtonDetailsReq) {
    object[] results = this.Invoke("BMGetButtonDetails", new object[] {
                BMGetButtonDetailsReq});
    return ((BMGetButtonDetailsResponseType)(results[0]));
}
```

In general, is there any way to inspect the incoming **XML** in a *Web Reference*?  (VS2010)

Comment: Why are you using a Web Reference? Is there a reason to not use a Service Reference?

Comment: Paypal does not provide a Service Reference interface - at least, it doesn't work.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "Service Reference" interface. A Service Reference should work just as well as, or better than, a "Web Reference". "Web Reference" is just the old technology.

Comment: John, try to pick up the Paypal SOAP (designed for .NET 2.0) using "Service Reference", it won't work.  Service Reference seems to only work for WCF.

Comment: @tofu: sorry, it may not work for some reason, but you're totally mistaken about WCF. WCF totally replaces the older technology. It can do everything that ASMX technology could do, including consume basic SOAP 1.1 services.

Comment: @tofu: tried their WSDL, and they have a **BUG** at line 6550, according to XMLSpy: `<element name="FlowControlDetails" type="ns:FlowControlDetailsType" minOccurs="0" maxOccur="1">`. The word they're looking for is `maxOccurs`.

Comment: @tofu: I guess that's in eBLBaseComponents.xsd line 6550. In any case, copying the WSDL and XSDs to disk and fixing that one problem allowed "Add Service Reference" to succeed.

Comment: See https://www.x.com/thread/53139

Comment: John, you are absolutely right.  I fixed maxOccurs to get it into the Web Reference and forgot to give Service Reference a try again.

Comment: @tofu: better link: https://www.x.com/thread/52802. They've known about this for some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp)** is a great HTTP proxy/inspection tool for inspecting HTTP and/or SOAP traffic.

**Edit**

Tips on tracing over SSL **[here](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp)**

Comment: Looks like it is encrypted behind https - no sign of any Xml.

Comment: I guess it is a good thing - when clicking on Decrypt SSL, I get System.Net.WebException was unhandled by user code
  Message=The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
  Source=System.Web.Services

Comment: @mjmarsh - I was able to get past the SSL/TLS error using "ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };" and VS is now throwing the original error.  However, in Fiddler I only see the original CONNECT, but no data.

Comment: Turns out that I had to recheck Decrypt SSL.  This worked.  Thanks mjmarsh!

Answer (score 1):

The reason I was beating on the "Service Reference vs. Web Reference" drum again was that using Service References gives you an out of the box solution for watching the XML. Just use the [Configuration Editor Tool (SvcConfigEditor.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732009.aspx) to turn on [Message Logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx).